# Как посчитать количество дочерних блоков кодом JS

Tags: javascript, html

Мне надо сделать так что, если у меня в родительском блоке считало количество блоков.
Например если у меня в родительском блоке 6 блоков и я добавил 7 блок то у меня выполнялось какое-то условие, или же если меньше 6 блоков так-же выполнялось условие.

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let childrenCount = document.querySelectorAll('.block .child-block').length;

if (childrenCount < 6) {
    console.log('меньше 6');
} else {
    console.log('больше или равно 6');
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
  <div class="child-block"></div>
</div>
```